# Is there something like tap in RxJS that ignores notification type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In general `tap` pipe is for side-effects such as logging. In my case I just want to set `isLoading` property to `false`. The key is this place shouldn't care whether it's next or error type of notification but still tap needs to have it distinguished to work so I need to have duplicated code:

```
something.pipe(
    tap({
        next: () => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        },
        error: () => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    }),
)
```

Is there any pipe, or some way to configure tap so I just provide one callback function which would run no matter what the notification type is? Eg.

```
something.pipe(
    anyTap(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
    }),
)
```

And whatever `something` returns, `anyTap` would run it's callback function anyway.

Comment: Yeah that's a anti-pattern. Why do you need to do this kind of side effects in the first place ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Well in this case I need to hide a loader so it should be hidden whatever the response from API is. But yeah good to know that's an anti-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
something.pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you might define the anyType operator:

```ts
function anyTap<T>(fn: () => void): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return tap({
    next: _ => fn(),
    error: _ => fn(),
    complete: fn
  });
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```ts
something.pipe(
    anyTap(() => this.isLoading = false),
)
```